# Entity Framework code-first isn't saving data

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to accomplish a table splitting pattern by split Person | PersonData on a 1:1 relationship with Entity Framework 5. And I'm doing it using the code-first approach, because for some reason EF 5.0 doesn't like 1:1 relationships as model-first which IMHO sucks badly.

Both `Person` and `PersonData` got their `ID` columns set as identity in SQL Server like that:

**Person** table:

```
|ID|
|Name|
|.....|
```

**PersonData** table:

```
|ID|
|ID_Person|
|.....|
```

Just after a `SaveChanges()` command SQL returns that I cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table.

Then I changed my `PersonData` map file:

```
this.HasKey(t => t.ID).Property(p =>
p.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

And tried again. Now I get

> *A dependent property in a `ReferentialConstraint` is mapped to a
>   store-generated column. Column: 'ID'.*

What should I change?

Comment: EF 5.0 can do 1:1 relationships in model-first with no problems

Comment: No it doesnt. Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Blablalah' in relationship 'Blabalbala'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be *.

Comment: You do it through class inheritance. In this case PersonData would inherit from Person. It's very straightforward.

Comment: Why would PersonData have an identity column? Surely ID_Person would be a foreign key and primary key.

Comment: What does that even mean? What is the benefit of an identity column when you have a unique identifier in the form of ID_Person anyway?

Comment: @ta.speot.is Agree, One unique identifier is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must map `PersondData` primary key as foreign key to `Person`. `ID_Person` in this case cannot be used because it would result in one-to-many relationship (EF doesn't support unique constraints and without uniqueness it cannot build one-to-one relationship).